# MySQL с кучей JOIN на вебсайте как быть?

Tags: mysql, join

Стою на перепутье, не знаю что выбрать, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Есть БД с таблицей товаров и некоторых их свойств в отдельных таблицах, а точнее:

```
good (~2k Записей)
catalog (~50 записей)
form (4 записи)
type (~100 записей)
color (10 записей)
sostav (5 записей)
sizes (~200)
width (~50)
```

[image: Схема БД]

Соответственно, в каждой из этих 11 (включая таблицы связей `<->`) таблицах N-ное кол-во колонок. В общей сложности, порядка 150 со всех таблиц.

Вопрос - как лучше сделать:

1. 6 разных запросов только с нужными JOIN и колонками (1 на выборку товаров и 5 для отображения фильтров) + JOINы и условия, если выбраны фильтры и/или сортировка
2. Хранимая процедура из запроса со всеми JOIN и всеми колонками и дальнейшая обработка всей этой каши в PHP (совсем не оптимально, на мой взгляд, но мало ли)
3. 1 запрос во временную таблицу и дальнейшие выборки из нее (все еще долго, т.к. сам по себе полный запрос выполняется от 2 до 20 секунд) + если не ошибаюсь, временная таблица будет создаваться для каждого открытого соединения отдельно. Соответственно 20 одновременных юзеров - 20 временных таблиц из ~300к строк
4. Создать таблицу содержащую результат выборки всех JOIN, с составным PK по всем PK входящих таблиц и индексами на нужных колонках и периодически ее обновлять. Скажем, раз в час/5часов/день.
5. Вариант 4, но обновлять данные по триггерам (пока не знаю, можно ли в триггере), данные о товарах обновляются не часто, но по многу за раз и каждый раз вызывать триггеры... Добавить 1 товар связать его с 5ю размерами - 6 вызовов триггера, как минимум... + типы + цвета... (за день манагер может изменить/добавить 10-50 товаров)
6. **Какой то нормальный вариант?**

В любом случае, минимальный набор JOIN который должен быть во всех запросах:

```
goods - собственно, товары
catalogs - категории товаров (для проверки вкл/выкл)
size_type_1 - размеры (для проверки остатков)
```

Так же, в каждом запросе будет расчет `в наличии`/`нет в наличии` + HAVING по этому расчету для фильтров (там должны быть только актуальные данные)

Вот такая передо мной задачка встала. Вроде бы, все подробно, как смог описал.
Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь :)

Comment: в чем проблема запустить их по очереди и посмотреть время выполнения?

Comment: сделайте хр процедуру, запускайте кроном каждые 5  минут и все. не должно быть проблем

Comment: А вы фильтры хотите "живые". Т.е. если человек выбрал уже 1 фильтр например размер, то в фильтре по цветам отображать только те цвета которые есть с данными размерами. Если нет - то сами фильтры это select из справочной таблицы и все. И его можно вообще отдельно закешировать и отдавать готовый. Если "живые", то конечно сложнее, надо по выбираемым товарам отбирать. но это можно делать и без склеек если названия у вас уже закешированы, а основной запрос полюбому id вернет, они же есть в goods

Comment: @Jean-Claude, проблема в том, что данные могут меняться. На текущих данных все может быть ок, а потом появятся проблемы.

Comment: @Vfvtnjd то есть, вы за вариант 4, если я правильно понял?

Comment: @Mike, да - фильтры как раз живые. С другими я бы и не заморачивался так. Ваш вариант с выборкой только товаров мог бы прокатить, если бы не было связей много-ко-многому. По сути, если я верно понял ваше предложение, мы просто разобьем 1 транзакцию с несколькими JOIN на несколько транзакций, по сути, делающих тоже самое. Я не про в MySQL, но мне кажется, что это будет еще дольше... Нет?

Comment: Если потом опять обращаться в БД - то да, будет дольше. Но справочники можно держать в памяти - они же не большие. Кстати у вас в вопросе не прослеживается многие ко многим. написано так, как будто из goods прямая связь к справочнику. Раз многие ко многим, то получать фильтры можно отдельно. Вам для этого саму таблицу товаров использовать не надо. Кстати по вопросу не ясно как такие связи многие-многие поддерживаются одной таблицей для всех видов фильтров или для каждого своя. Во втором случае тащить в основной запрос их просто нельзя, там будет громадный объем когда они перемножаться

Comment: @Mike , да, у каждого свойства своя таблица связи. Многое ко многим я пометил двойной стрелкой `<->`. Почему мне не нужно тянуть товары? Мне же нужно получить ID товаров полученных на предыдущем этапе фильтрации и для них получить доступные свойства. И по объему данных - да, вы правы. JOIN всего на все отдает порядка 300k строк на приведенных в посте данных.

Comment: Но id товара отлично получаются из таблицы связи, таблица товаров не нужна что бы получить список id и приклеить следующую таблицу. Вообще у меня нет рекомендаций, что делать если таблица связи отдельная на каждое свойство. можно разве что сделать многоуровневый запрос на каждом уровне джоинится одна таблица и группируется до id товара.

Comment: Лучше было бы делать единую таблицу связи на все свойства. Правда у нее есть минусы - ключами ссылки не проверишь. Так что она может быть в паралель остальным и дублировать их. Что то вроде ('ТипСвойства', 'id-товара','id-свойства') или даже без типа, если id всех свойств в едином пространстве из одного справочника. Тут в общем то вопрос как справочники организовать

Comment: @Mike, понял вас. Спасибо за советы. Буду думать

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всем спасибо.

Остановился на неком промежуточном варианте: таблица кэша, содержащая ID всех связных таблиц, полученных через полную выборку JOINом всех таблиц.

Создал избыточные связи и комбинированный индекс, по самым часто используемым полям, на этой таблице. Индекс получился "избыточный". Для таблицы в ~10мб индекс получился ~36мб. Но такой индекс нужен. Сравнил вариант InnoDB + индекс и MEMORY без индекса. Даже в памяти все запросы выполнялись больше 3х секунд, против < 0.5 сек в таблице с индексами.

Средняя скорость выполнения запроса почти любой сложности только с нужными JOIN, в итоге, получилась ~0.003 сек (полная выборка, правда, с любым JOIN без условий выполняется ~0.7 сек, но она и не будет использоваться), против 2-20 сек с разными вариантами в старт посте.

Единственный минус - таблицу придется обновлять "ручками" или по расписанию. Остановился на варианте "ручками", то есть, таблица кэша будет обновляться только после обновления остатков товаров. Т.к. даже если манагер добавит товар, пока не обновятся остатки, пользователи этот товар не найдут.

Итоговая модель такая вышла, кому интересно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]